# Why is the star (*) operator faster than pointer access multiplication in matrix scaling using OpenCV?

Tags: performance, opencv, matrix

I'm trying to learn how to manipulate OpenCV matrix values in the most optimized way. I tried scaling a large image stored in OpenCV matrix four different ways.

1) Using the star `*` operator

2) Using `at` function and `for` loops

3) Using pointer access and `for` loops

4) Using a lookup table

The rounded results of this experiment were as follows

`*` operator ------- `3 ms`

`at` function ------- `12 ms`

pointer access ---- `9 ms`

lookup table -------- `1 ms`

Now it is pretty obvious as to why lookup tables are the fastest. But I'm not always going to be able to use them. For the cases that I can't use a lookup table for, I need to understand how OpenCV implements scaling using the `*` operator so I can use that method as reference in my other matrix value manipulations.

I would very much appreciate it if someone could tell me what happens behind the `*` operation that makes it faster than the pointer access method?

Please find the following code for your reference.

Thanks,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <chrono>

typedef std::chrono::system_clock Timer;
typedef std::chrono::duration<double> Duration;

using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::vector;

double profile(Timer::time_point start, Timer::time_point end) {
    Duration span = end - start;
    return span.count() * 1000;
}

int main() {

    cv::Mat image = cv::imread("../data/large.jpg", 0);
    float sc = 1;

    while (true) {

        //=================== first method ====================
        Timer::time_point s1 = Timer::now();
        cv::Mat mine = image * sc;
        Timer::time_point s2 = Timer::now();

        //=================== second method ====================
        cv::Mat yours(image.size(), image.type());
        Timer::time_point s3 = Timer::now();
        for (int i = 0; i < image.rows; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < image.cols; j++) {
                yours.at<uchar>(i, j) = image.at<uchar>(i, j) * sc;
            }
        }
        Timer::time_point s4 = Timer::now();

        //=================== third method ====================
        if (!image.isContinuous()) {
            std::cerr << "ERROR: image matrix isn't stored as a 1D array" << endl;
            exit(-1);
        }
        Timer::time_point s5 = Timer::now();
        cv::Mat result(image.size(), image.type());
        for (int i = 0; i < image.rows; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < image.cols; j++) {
                result.data[i * image.cols + j] = image.data[i * image.cols + j] * sc;
            }
        }
        Timer::time_point s6 = Timer::now();

        //=================== fourth method ====================
        Timer::time_point s7 = Timer::now();
        cv::Mat lookupTable(1, 256, image.type());
        for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
            lookupTable.data[i] = i * sc;
        cv::Mat his;
        cv::LUT(image, lookupTable, his);
        Timer::time_point s8 = Timer::now();


        cout << "first = " << profile(s1, s2) << endl;
        cout << "second = " << profile(s3, s4) << endl;
        cout << "third = " << profile(s5, s6) << endl;
        cout << "fourth = " << profile(s7, s8) << endl;
        cout << "=============== " << endl;

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There's a major difference between the first approach and the rest -- the first one saturates, the other 3 overflow.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I did a bit of research about what you mentioned but I couldn't fully understand what you meant by saturation vs overflow in this case. Would you mind explaining a bit more?

Comment: https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.0/db/de0/group__core__utils.html#gab93126370b85fda2c8bfaf8c811faeaf | You're multiplying 8bit unsigned int by float and storing the result as an 8bit unsigned int (i.e. the values can fall into range 0-255). Imagine scenario such as `128 * 2.0f` -- result is `256.0f`, converted to integer it's 256 (or 0x100). We can only store 8 bits, so during regular cast, the higher bits are ignored. Hence you get a 0. However, with saturation, values higher than can be represented are reduced to the maximum possible value -- in this case 255.

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation. It makes sense. Yet, I'm trying to figure out how this casting comes into play and affect the performance in the above scenario? Do you think that factors in greatly in the performance here?

Comment: I was mostly pointing it out so that you don't end up comparing apples and oranges. Also, in second method you don't time the allocation of the result matrix, whereas elsewhere you do. | In many cases the saturation will take more time, since it's additional operations to do, so method one is at a disadvantage here. Might explain why LUT has so much advantage... (lookups aren't that great when you have SIMD) | As you discovered, doing it in place is way faster, which suggests allocation of result introduces noticeable overhead. (True from experience)

Comment: I appreciate your thorough answer. It was very helpful. The thing with the lookup table is that, I won't be able to use them all the time since there are many cases in which the final output cannot be computed and stored in the table beforehand. I believe the major advantage of the lookup here is that I do the multiplication only 256 times versus having to do it for every single pixel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Operator *() used parallel_for! So it will be faster than single threaded function. And you can write #pragma omp parallel for before rows-loop and compare results. Or you can use image.forEach - it is also parallel and fast.

cv::LUT: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/core/src/lut.cpp#L359

This function has a set of implementations: opencl, openvx, ipp and simple with parallel_for. I think that in your case was used ipp_lut, very-very optimized version from Intel for their processors. And it is fast!

Comment: Thank you so much for your insightful answer. That makes perfect sense. Also, I wasn't aware of `Mat::forEach` functionality, I will include that in my experiment and check the performance boost.

Comment: I implemented the same thing using `Mat::forEach` and it runs at `2 ms` which is even faster than the `*` operator. Yet the fastest by far is when I do `image *= sc` which runs hyper fast at about `0.0014 ms` and the reason could be there's no memory allocation or data copying and the operation is done on the native pixel values.